# Realizations of random variable

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Can some of you help me with following exercise?

> Provide a procedure to generate realizations of a random variable with
>   CDF (cumulative distribution function) $Fx(x)$ given by:
>
> $Fx(x)=(x+1)/4$ if   $-1<x<0$
>
> $Fx(x)=(x+3)/4$ if $0<=x<1$

What is the meaning of *generate realizations of random variable*?

Thank all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what is meant is: produce (pseudo-) random numbers.
Note that for a distribution function $F$ and its inverse $F^{-1}$ and a uniform random variable $U$ it holds that
$ F^{-1}(U) $ has distribution $F$. You an google random number generation and find this procedure.
In you case:

1. find the inverse of $F$
2. Generate uniform random variables
3. Apply $F^{-1}$

Then you are done. Which programming language do you use?

Edit: As remarked by Macro there is an atom at $0$ with probabilty $\frac12$. I think we can still use the inverse in the following way:

1. find the inverse for $x \in [-1,0)$ and $x \in (0,1]$
2. Generate a uniform $U$
3. Call the generated rv $X$

   3.a) If $U \in [0,\frac14]$ then apply $F^{-1}$ as definded on the left of $0$ and set $X = F^{-1}(U)$

   3.b) If $U \in (\frac14,\frac34)$ then set $X = 0$

   3.c) If $U \in [\frac34,1]$  then apply $F^{-1}$ as definded on the right of $0$ and set $X = F^{-1}(U)$.

This should take care for the atom. Note that I did not care about open or closed intervals in the definition above as the probability for the uniform to reach the the point at the interval end is zero.

Comment: No, I am not using a programming language.Is a normal exercise of statistics.

Comment: there you can get unform random variables with a function and then you apply the inverse ... you can make it in Excel! :)

Comment: Oh: I read Excel ... exercise .. anyways, the path should be clear. Best,R

Comment: Macro yes, you are right, I missed the discontinuity. @lui14 please look at Macro's remark!

Comment: @Macro: inverse transform sampling should be possible here when using the generalized inverse, i.e. $F^{-1}(u) = \inf\;\{x \mid F(x)\geq u, 0<u<1\}$

Comment: Ok thank for yours opinion and advice,so @Macro what do you suggest to resolve that?

Comment: I hope the way that I edited the answer is correct now. It is Friday night in Europe and I have to go off-line soon. If there is still something important missing, then please @Macro post the correct answer and lui14 can choose yours.